# How to get attachements URL from author meta and display them?

Tags: images, uploads, author

I created a form for edit author with "WP User Frontend" and I use a custom meta field for multi upload images that can upload 6 images, with meta name `'management_certi'`. My problem is I can display first image uploaded, but can't display all of the images uploaded from its form for author.
My code is:

```
if ( get_the_author_meta( 'management_certi', $curauth->ID ) ) { 
    $id = get_the_author_meta( 'management_certi', $curauth->ID ); 
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $id ); 
    ?><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title=""><img src="<?php 
        echo $url; ?>" class="thumbnail" width="36" height="36" /></a><?php 
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :D Yeeeeeeeeaaaahhhhhh :)))) 
This is final code that worked! I explained each level ;)

```
/* for get author ID use these */
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
$author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');

/* First condition */
if( get_the_author_meta('management_certi', $author_id, true)) {
    /* get file ID */
    $id = get_user_meta( $author_id, 'management_certi');

    if($id) {
        /* Array Loop! */
        foreach($id as $attachments) {
            /* get file URL */
            $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachments ); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title=""><img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="thumbnail" width="36" height="36" /></a>
        <?php
        }
    }
} else { echo '--'; }
```